# Angular 2 redirect on page load

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-cookies

In my Angular 2 app i would like to have a redirect to a certain page if a cookie is set. The behavior should be:

- No cookie -> Normal routing
- Cookie is set -> Redirect to the saved route which was set within the cookie

What may be the best practice to do this? My idea is to use ngOnInit() within root component AppComponent, then check if a cookie is set and maybe redirect if the current url is not the same from the cookie.

Is this a possible solution?

My first problem was that `this.router.url` is always "/" within AppComponent.

Also navigating within ngOnInit() in AppComponent doesnt work: `this.router.navigate(['/stepX']);`

Comment: try `thos.router.navigate(...)` wrapped with `setTimeout(...)` in `ngOnInit`

Comment: I guess a canActivate Guard is best solution. I can do my checks there, navigate if needed and return false to prevent the regular routing. setTimeout doesn't seem to be any solid solution to be honest.

Comment: If I considered it a solid solution, I had posted it as answer instead as of comment. I just tried to track down where the issue comes from.